# 10 meter USB cable works with WiFi Adapter, but not simpler devices

Tags: usb

Despite initial issues, I could finally put my 10 meter USB cable to work. As it turns out, the front USB ports could not provide enough power for this cable; but the ports on the back could.

With that said, a surprising issue has emerged. I can operate my WiFi adapter dongle on the other end of the 10 meter cable, but not simpler devices. My input devices such as a mouse or keyboard should not draw much power. But they aren't recognized; the mouse would light up, the keyboard Num-Lock would not. My USB hub is not recognized, neither is my bluetooth adapter. These two would light up; for the hub the PC explicitly shows up a message "This device is not recognized".

So why is this?

You would naturally wonder why I am attempting to set up input devices on the other end of a 10 meter cable. I actually have an elaborate plan (if not naive). The hub is to harbor input devices and the WiFi adapter, the PC is to broadcast as a hotspot, my Tablet is to connect to the hotspot and a VNC server would allow me to remotely control the PC from the Tablet. The 10 meter cable keeps the input devices within my reach.

[A diagram describing my naive scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCIYi.png)

Comment: Could you draw a block diagram of what you are trying to accomplish? Where is PC, where the 10m cable goes, which peripherals you want and where, etc. And why do you need the WiFi adapter on the 10-m cable (wifi has a pretty long range).

Comment: @Ali Chen Okay, the hub in the other end of the 10 meter cable should harbor my input devices(and this is a must), but not necessarily the WiFi adapter.

Comment: You still never answered the question which cable (USB2 or USB3) you are trying to deploy, and what kind of devices (hub, WiFi, power schema) you are using. Draw a diagram

Comment: What kind of 10m cable do you have? What kind of connectors does it have? I guess Type-A plug on one end. What is on the other end? Type-A receptacle, right? Maybe you can take a picture, so both ends are visible from their openings? I see no AC-DC power adapter in the diagram.

Answer (score 3):

Different devices have different current drains. There will be substantial voltage loss over that distance where the effects you experience will be unusual. I would use a 10 meter rj45 cable and some usb/rj45 adapters instead to get your devices to work over this distance. The adapters are powered so compensate for any voltage loss.